# how to pass a parameter between 2 components and use it inside a "componentWillMount()" - I'm using react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

this is an example of what I need

```
// This view should receive the parameter before render()
componentWillMount(){
    fetch(parameterHere)
}
```

This image is just a picture of the code above.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRdib.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question needs more details. Please, provide code and context will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass values between parent-child components by passing it as a prop to the child from the parent.

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <ComponentB mProp={someValue}/>
    }
}

class ComponentB extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch(this.props.mProp);
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

pass values between two children by lifting that prop into a shared parent component and managing that prop's value in the parent component

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    onChangeMProp = (newValue) => {
        this.setState({ someValue: newValue });
    }

    render() {
        const { someValue } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentA 
                    onChangeMProp={this.onChangeMProp} 
                    mProp={someValue}
                />
                <ComponentB 
                    onChangeMProp={this.onChangeMProp} 
                    mProp={someValue}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Tyler, I will try this solution. I'm new at react native but it has great stuff